# How to program NAO Robot remotely

Tags: webserver, nao-robot, ros2

For my internship I have to create a new framework on ROS2 to control NAO remotely. I have to use Python 3 so I can't use the Python SDK furnished by the constructor because the latest version is 2.7, which makes the things more complex.

My tutor told me to try to use a web server instead. Concretely, the ROS2 message would be sent to a web server and then sent from it to Nao. I succeeded to send them to a server but I don't know how to make Nao understand the message received from the server, and even how to send them.

Do you have any ideas which could help me please ?

Answer (score 1):

Haru.

I am quite new with Nao Robot, but as far as I know, you can use C++ to create a ROS package.

Can you consider this option?

Good luck !

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending it to a web server, use [libQi](http://doc.aldebaran.com/libqi/) (either C++ or Python), to connect directly to NAOqi. Note that there is [a ROS 1 component for NAOqi](https://github.com/ros-naoqi/naoqi_driver) already.

In a nutshell, wherever you would use an `ALProxy(...)` with the NAOqi SDK, instead you would retrieve get a service from a session with `session->service(...)`.